# Google Apps password change not reflected across all devices

Tags: security, outlook, g-suite, blackberry

We have a paid Google Apps account and I recently changed the password for one of our users. I confirmed the password change by logging into gmail.com using the new password. The old password isn't obviously working.

The user has been using this account on his Outlook(with Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook) and Blackberry. I told him to enter the new password when he is asked but it has been more than 24 hours and neither Outlook or Blackberry has asked for his new password!

He tried rebooting both computer and Blackberry but they continue to work fine, without him entering the new password - he is able to send and receive mails like before.

Is this normal behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Google Admin Panel there is a user option under "Profile" I believe to force them to sign in again.

I am looking for an Image to help you and I will add it when I find one.